# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have an application concists of uitextview (self.animalDesciption) , and button

I use the button to update database with the text in the uitextview 
but it always give EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the line

NSString *NewData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", @"Update animals set description = ",TheNewText , " Where name =  ",the_user];

the full code is

```
sqlite3 *database;
// Setup some globals
NSString *databaseName = @"test.sql";

// Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
[databasePath retain];
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

NSString * TheNewText = self.animalDesciption.text; 
[TheNewText retain];

NSString * the_user = AnimalName ;
[ the_user retain];

NSString *NewData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", @"Update animals set description = ",TheNewText , " Where name =  ",the_user];

[NewData retain] ;

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sqlStatement = [NewData UTF8String];



if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK) {

sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
}
```

any suggestion please

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`NSString *NewData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", @"Update animals set description = ",TheNewText , @" Where name =  ",the_user];`

Note the @"Where name = "

Comment: it worked very well, the problem is it not execute the query not enter to sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "@" before the string " Where name =  ".
Try:

```
NSString *NewData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", @"Update animals set description = ",TheNewText , @" Where name =  ",the_user];
```